# Pygame taking FOREVER to load

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, pygame, loading

I have been working on a street-fighter like game and suddenly my code takes forever to load.
My code is only 274 lines.
And everytime I close the window, it fully loads.
If you need code, ask.

Please help

Comment: _If you need code, ask._  Without your code nobody is able to help you. Edit your question and add your code, especially if it's only 274 lines.

Comment: use `print()` in many places to see which part of code is executed. Maybe you created infinity loop and it never ends run it.

Comment: you should put code in question. If you can't then put at least link to code on pastebin, github or other server. Name of you account is no needed

Comment: My guess: just some indentation wrong or something wrong with the event handling.

Comment: here: https://pastebin.com/Kujtscaa

Comment: as @sloth said you have wrong indentation in almost last line with `redrawgamewin()`  (before `pygame.quit()`) and it is not inside loop so it never redraw image in window.

Comment: @furas feel free to post an answer

Comment: @furas Thanks! Ive been on this code for a long time i cant even find the smallest problems!

Answer (score 3):

As @sloth said you have wrong indentation in almost last line with `redrawgamewin()`

```
 redrawgamewin() 
 pygame.quit()
```

and it is not inside loop so it never redraw image in window.

You would need

```
     redrawgamewin() 
 pygame.quit()
```